# How to get childs of this JSON Object in Java

Tags: java, json, org.json

I am using volley to post data to the server and this is the response I get from the server.

```
{"result":[{"result":"success","id":"345"}]}
```

How can I get value of `id` from this response.

I tried like this, but I get whole `JSONArray` in response.

```
JSONArray obj = new JSONObject(response).getJSONArray("result"); 
JSONArray resp = obj.optJSONArray(0);
```

How to get value of `id` & `result`?

Comment: Which JSON library are you using? JSON is not part of Java's runtime library.

Comment: Maven Repository

Answer (score 0):

> How to get value of `id` & `result`?

Since you have on your hands a `JSONArray`, which is comprised of `JSONObject`s, you can iterate over this array accessing each `JSONObject` and retrieving its properties.

For convenience, we can define a POJO that would correspond to `JSONObject`. It can be represented either as a `class` or a Java 16 `record`, I'll go with a record because of its conciseness:

```
public record Result(String result, int id) {}
```

That's how we can parse a `JSONArray` into a `List` of POJO:

```
String response = """
    {"result":[{"result":"success","id":"345"}]}
""";
    
JSONArray array = new JSONObject(response).getJSONArray("result");
        
List<Result> results = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject res = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
    results.add(new Result(res.getString("result"), res.getInt("id")));
}
        
results.forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output:*

```
Result[result=success, id=345]
```

Alternatively, this logic can be implemented using Stream API. To generate a stream from a `JSONArray` we can make use of the functionality offered by `StreamSupport` utility class.

```
JSONArray array = new JSONObject(response).getJSONArray("result");
        
List<Result> results = StreamSupport.stream(array.spliterator(), false) // Stream<Object>
    .map(JSONObject.class::cast) // Stream<JSONObject>
    .map(jsonObject ->           // Stream<Result>
        new Result(jsonObject.getString("result"), jsonObject.getInt("id"))
    )
    .toList(); // for Java 16+ or collect(Collectors.toList())
```